# No rule to process .xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I recently changed my project structure and get a warning about my core data model file. What I do is I add my xcdatamodeld file in the "**Build Phases > Compile Sources**" of my target and the compiler spits out the following warning:

```
Warning: no rule to process file '/Users/Documents/Services/sources/Services.xcdatamodeld' of type file for architecture armv7
```

I tried adding a custom rule for data model version files in "**Build rules**" but it doesn't make any difference.

[image: Custom Rule]

This results in my app crashing at launch when I try to instantiate a **NSManagedObjectModel** from my **Services.momd** file that's supposed to be copied in the app.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit - Found a solution**

For some reason, specifying a custom rule handling files with the .xcdatamodeld extension fixed it. Don't know why the predefined apple ones didn't do it.

[image: Custom rule]

Comment: What did you do to your project that broke this?

Comment: It's a huge project in a workspace, we used to have it fragmented into smaller projects, compile the whole thing into a static library (for obscure reasons to me). We were then copying manually the momd file via build scripts. We recently changed to using one single project and doing things more cleanly and this broke. I actually found a way to fix it (check my edit).